# Mysql Performance Impact with long integer field

Tags: mysql, crc, crc64

I wants to store crc64 of a string which is 20+ digits long number. I wants to understand performance consequences of storing big numeric digits in terms of space complexity and JOINS.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: a bigint unsigned is 8 bytes and runs from 0 to 18446744073709551615 so though 20 digits, not completely. Eight bytes is pretty thin in my book. But it would appear that you are [All Set and Ok](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn-history/r49/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/general_functions.html) with an unsigned bigint. So have an index on the aforementioned.

Comment: I must admit it is an interesting question. It's implications being that which wasn't the same, becomes the same (barring any mathematical tomfoolery)